# Interpretation of momentum in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, momentum, mass

Consider an inelastic collision between two particles $A$ and $B$ of the same mass $m$, such that after the collision they come to rest WRT an inertial frame K. In this frame, both the particles approach each other with equal speeds, $v_0$ at an angle of $\alpha$ WRT to $x-$axis

Now consider a frame K$_1$ Moving with the same horizontal velocity as $A$. In this frame, $A$ has only vertical velocity, $u$, while $B$ moves with velocity $u'=u/\gamma$, in the negative y-direction. Since after the collision particles stick, the final momentum in the y-direction must be zero, which we can see is not the case as $mu\neq mu'$, according to non-relativistic mechanics. However, if we let mass depend on velocity then

$$m_1u=m_2u' \\ ‎\\  m_2=\gamma m_1 $$

However this seems in contradiction to the usual definition of mass increasing with velocity, since here $u>u'$, thus since $m_1$ has more velocity its mass should be more massive but as we can see this is not the case from the above equations. How is this contradiction solved?

Comment: Putting this as a comment, as can't expand: the mass of a body in SRT is its inertial mass in its rest frame, i.e. the momentary comoving inertial frame.

Comment: The underlying conceptual issue for this question is in how to apply conservation of momentum in SR.  You might get more useful answers if you change the title to ask about momentum, rather than mass.

Comment: "However this seems in contradiction to the usual definition of mass increasing with velocity" <-- This is NOT the usual definition of mass. Mass does NOT change with velocity. Relativistic mass is an outdated concept.

Answer (score 3):

There are many questions here about mass in S.R.  The contemporary interpretation is that there is only rest mass.  Rest energy is an invariant quantity. Therefore mass, $m = E_0 / c^2$, is too.

Your problem is not resolved by redefining mass.  It is resolved by using the correct, relativistic definition of momentum, and using the [relativistic velocity addition rule in 2D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula#Standard_configuration).

The relativistic definition of momentum is $\vec{p} = \gamma m \vec{v}$, where the speed that appears in the Lorentz factor is the speed of that particle as measured in the frame in question.
$$\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{{v_x}^2+{v_y}^2+{v_z}^2}{c^2}}} $$
In the K frame both particles have the same magnitude of velocity, so $\gamma$ is the same for both.  In this frame the total momentum is
$$\vec{p}_\mathrm{tot} = \gamma m(v_x, v_y) + \gamma m(-v_x, -v_y) = 0.$$
In the K$_1$ reference frame, the two particles have different speeds, so each gets its own Lorentz factor, $\gamma_A \ne \gamma_B$.  To calculate these, you'll first need to find the velocity components of each particle in the new reference frame.

As a reminder, momentum is not an invariant quantity.  Just like in Newtonian mechanics, different observers will measure the momentum of a system to be different.  Within a given reference frame momentum is conserved.  But just because $\vec{p} = 0$ in the K frame, that does not mean $\vec{p}=0$ in all frames.  In fact the total momentum of this system is not zero in K$_1$.

The coordinate Lorentz transformation only changes spatial coordinates in the direction of motion of the reference frame.  But velocity transforms differently.  No matter what direction the frame moves, all components of velocity transform.  Your K$_1$ frame moves in the $x$ direction.  You can see that this causes the $y$-components of velocity to transform when you consider $v_y = \frac{dy}{dt}$.  The spatial part, $dy$, is unchanged by the Lorentz transformation, but $dt$ is.  So $v_y \ne v_y^\prime$.

I would recommend stating your problem in terms of vector components, $v_x, v_y, v_z$ and working from there.  Calculate the velocity components in each frame, compute $\gamma$ for each particle in each frame. Then you can see that the total momentum is conserved in each frame before and after the collision, but the magnitude of momentum in different frames is different.

Comment: You may want to expand the 2nd to last pargraph for clarity: i.e. the directional dependence implies that there is no scalar that describes the inertia of a body in an arbitary frame as you need to also need to know its velocity.

Comment: So much confusion would be avoided if theorists would just put the subscript 0 on rest mass.

Comment: There is no need to, since there's only one parameter called mass in current use. The confusion only comes from people who try to resurrect the old ghost of relativistic mass (which was already a joke in workshops when I worked in particle physics 20 years ago).

Comment: @JohnDoty the rest mass in special reaitvity is the nearest equivalent to the inertial mass in Newtonian dyamics. The difference is that need to work with 4-vectors, rather than 3-vectors. To see how troublesome concepts of "relativistic" mass are,  to recreate the f = ma in SR where f is 3-force and a 3-acceleration, you need m to be a 3x3 matrix!

Comment: @JohnDavis You pick your troubles. 4-vectors are more convenient for certain problems, relativistic mass is more convenient for others. Without relativistic mass, the explanation for the mass of a photon trapped in a resonator is contrived.

Comment: @Miyase In theoretical particle physics, relativistic mass is an inconvenient abstraction. But that's a specialized corner of physics.

Comment: @JohnDoty I was working with people in experimental particle physics (mostly LEP or LHC teams). Relativistic mass wasn't in use.

Comment: @Miyase The death of relativistic mass has been greatly exaggerated. See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotron#Relativistic_considerations. When the machinery is motionless in the lab frame, and only the particles are relativistic, it makes sense to use lab frame concepts.

Comment: @Miyase Were you working with the actual experimental machinery (particle trackers, the accelerator itself, ...), or with data mathematically abstracted from the real physical measurements?

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look. At the end of the day it's just a definition, we're always free to give a name to any mathematically defined quantity. The point is just to know whether it's relevant or not.

Comment: @JohnDoty I was on the theoretical side probably more than half the time, but I spent time on both (especially one team that worked on parts of the LHC).

Comment: @JohnDoty, I think the mass-like quantity applied to a photon in a resonator would be effective mass rather than relativsitc mass. Relativstic mass gain can be useful device to intuit the LS barrier, but it can also be misleading as inertia depends on rest mass and the direction the force is applied relative to the direction of motion. A single scalar can't hold all the information needed.

Comment: @JohnDavis It's enough for some problems, not enough for others. That's what *used* to be taught when physics was more focused on the physical, less on the abstract.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to work such problems in relativity is to use the concept of [four-vectors](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html). There is a little bit of a learning curve, but if you are going to spend any time doing relativity the concept is well worth the effort.

One major four-vector is the [four-momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-momentum). In units where c=1 this is defined as $P=(E,p_x,p_y,p_z)$. The [Minkowski norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-momentum#Minkowski_norm) of the four-momentum is the mass: $-|P|^2=m^2=E^2-p^2$. This concept of mass is also called the "invariant mass" and is the usual meaning of the unadorned word "mass" that mainstream physicists use today. This meaning of mass is important because it is both conserved and invariant.

So, specifically for your problem, in the original frame before the collision we would have $$P_A=\left(\frac{m}{\sqrt{1-{v_x}^2-{v_y}^2}},\frac{m v_x}{\sqrt{1-{v_x}^2-{v_y}^2}},\frac{m v_y}{\sqrt{1-{v_x}^2-{v_y}^2}},0 \right)$$  $$P_B=\left(\frac{m}{\sqrt{1-{v_x}^2-{v_y}^2}},\frac{-m v_x}{\sqrt{1-{v_x}^2-{v_y}^2}},\frac{-m v_y}{\sqrt{1-{v_x}^2-{v_y}^2}},0 \right)$$ Note that $-|P_A|=-|P_B|=m$, so each particle has the same mass before the collision. Now, still in the original frame, after the collision we have $$P_C=P_A+P_B=\left(\frac{2 m}{\sqrt{1-{v_x}^2-{v_y}^2}},0,0,0 \right)$$ and the mass of the combined particle is $-|P_C|=\frac{2m}{\sqrt{1-{v_x}^2-{v_y}^2}}>2m$

Now, to see what happens in the K' frame we simply apply the Lorentz transform to all of the four-vectors to get: $$P'_A=\left(\frac{m-m v_x^2}{\sqrt{\left(v_x^2-1\right) \left(v_x^2+v_y^2-1\right)}},0,\frac{m v_y}{\sqrt{-v_x^2-v_y^2+1}},0\right)$$  $$ P'_B= \left(\frac{m \left(v_x^2+1\right)}{\sqrt{\left(v_x^2-1\right)
   \left(v_x^2+v_y^2-1\right)}},-\frac{2 m
   v_x}{\sqrt{\left(v_x^2-1\right)
   \left(v_x^2+v_y^2-1\right)}},-\frac{m
   v_y}{\sqrt{-v_x^2-v_y^2+1}},0\right) $$  $$ P'_C = \left(\frac{2 m}{\sqrt{\left(v_x^2-1\right)
   \left(v_x^2+v_y^2-1\right)}},-\frac{2 m
   v_x}{\sqrt{\left(v_x^2-1\right)
   \left(v_x^2+v_y^2-1\right)}},0,0\right) $$

I leave it as an exercise for the interested reader to show that the masses are unchanged meaning $-|P_i|=-|P'_i|$ which is the whole reason that we like the invariant mass.

> Since after the collision particles stick, the final momentum in the y-direction must be zero, which we can see is not the case

Indeed ${P'_C}_y=0$. Using the four-vector approach simplifies that.

> However this seems in contradiction to the usual definition of mass increasing with velocity, since here $u>u'$, thus since $m_1$ has more velocity its mass should be more massive but as we can see this is not the case from the above equations. How is this contradiction solved?

The usual definition of mass is the invariant mass. So using the usual definition of mass thre is no contradiction. Regardless of $v$ the mass is invariant. $-|P'_C|=-|P_C|$

What you are describing here is not the usual definition of mass but the relativistic mass, which is the same as $E$ in units where c=1. In the definition of the four momentum given above, notice that the first component, also called the time component, is equal to the total energy $E$. What used to be called the "relativistic mass" is now simply called the total energy. We see that ${P'_C}_t\ne{P_C}_t$, so although the invariant mass is the same in both frames the total energy is different between the two frames. By using four-vectors we have avoided the confusion between the mass and the total energy (sometimes called the "relativistic mass").